# Convert integral $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{y}^{\sqrt{4-y^2}} x^2+y^2 dx dy$ into polar form

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, polar-coordinates

Convert the following double integral to an equivalent polar form but do NOT evaluate:

$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{y}^{\sqrt{4-y^2}} x^2+y^2 \; dx \; dy.$$

Do we let $x=r\cos{(\theta)}$ and $y=r\sin{(\theta)}$ so $x^2+y^2=r^2$ and substitute in? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, since you just need to convert it to polar form... Is there any reason why you think it might not be?

Comment: sq, draw some x,y axes and then draw a picture of the thing.

Comment: How do I get the new limits of the bounds?

Comment: the outer integral is $y$ goes from $0$ to $1.$ For each such $y,$  $x$ goes from $y$ to $\sqrt {4-y^2}.$ One thing to be sorted out is, for any $y,$ is the square root actually bigger than $y$ itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]
Let $x=r\cos\theta$,  $y=r\sin\theta$ and $dxdy=rdr d\theta$. Note the integration region is a truncated circle sector as shown in the graph. Thus,
$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{y}^{\sqrt{4-y^2}}( x^2+y^2 )\; dx \; dy
=\int_{0}^{\frac\pi6}\int_{0}^2 r^3drd\theta
+\int_{\frac\pi6}^{\frac\pi4}\int_{0}^{1/\sin\theta} r^3drd\theta$$

Comment: $x=y$ bounds the region. The limits for $\theta$ should be $0\le \theta\le \frac {\pi}{4}.$  Then It appears that $y=1$ is an additional boundary.

Comment: @DougM - you're right thanks